# Error using embedded forms with Camunda Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I have my process(bpm file) defined as part of the Camunda Spring Boot project. I have a form attached to a Start Event. When I start my process I get "Form failure: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

I have checked Chrome console and found "XMLHttpRequest cannot load app:forms/my-form.html?noCache=1455724524763. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource" error message.

I had packaged the same process outside a Spring Boot project as a normal web app and deployed the war to Camunda Tomcat. It ran without any issue.

The issue happens when I package the same process as part of Camunda Spring Boot project.

Found 2 links describing similar issue but not helping much in terms of resolution.

https://github.com/plexiti/camunda-grails-plugin/issues/47

https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-2146

Does Camunda Spring Boot project support embedded form. I have not seen any example of embedded form for Camunda Spring Boot.

I am pretty much stuck. So any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the Tasklist can not determine the context path of the application. I just experienced that today in a customer training, when I undeployed a war file from a Wildfly.

A workaround could be to use an absolute path in the `formKey`, e.g. `embedded:/mywebapp/forms/my-form.html`

Comment: Thanks Falko.  I have tried as advised by you. I have tried embedded:/mywebapp/forms/my-form.html as well as embedded:mywebapp/forms/my-form.html. But my form still does not gets displayed. Though the error has now changed as I get " Form failure: No message available" error.  I do not get any error message in the Console either.  Kindly reiterating the point that this problem is occurring as I am packaging my process and the web app from withing Spring Boot application. I have previously tried this same setup outside Spring Boot app as a separate web app and it runs with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem as well. My coworker left this comment on the github issues of the project that you might find useful: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/issues/39

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't help and when I have time, I can probably give you a few more pointers.

Comment: Also in reply to the other answer, did you verify that the application was trying to request the form in the console. (When looking at the network traffic?)

Ours are also configured like Ours are also configured like  embedded:mywebapp/forms/my-form.html.

If it's making the network request, then there's probably just something wrong with your form.

Comment: As I have the same problem: Where is my Camunda application supposed to be accessible? My browser tries to find my declared form `embedded:app:forms/ergebnis-lesen.html` by calling the url `http://localhost:8080/forms/ergebnis-lesen.html?noCache=1529562907820&taskId=db51435d-751c-11e8-8c02-aced5cb84e54&userId=demo` which probably is wrong. But I don't even know the url where I can access the form :-/